# iOS App name displaying as $PRODUCT_NAME in simulator since starting to localize my app

Tags: ios, localization

I've just started to internationalize my app with NSLocalizedStrings, ready to localize it into French, German, and Italian. I've got no translations done yet so just make some dummy translations to convince myself that its working ok.

I'm still just working in the simulator and change its language to French to have a look at my dummy translated strings.

When doing so I notice that my App actually gets called $PRODUCT_NAME in the springboard, under the app icon. This is only when in non-english language settings, i've been testing it in French as described.

The actual strings exported into XLIFFs do include the $PRODUCT_NAME strings, but I just localize them back to $PRODUCT_NAME for all languages, hoping this would keep it evaluating as a VARIABLE look up.

I notice that my app does have BundleDisplayName properties that a small dummy app does not have, perhaps that's related.

Should I just stop the display name being tied to $PRODUCT_NAME, which itself is tied to $TARGET_NAME and explicitly write it out as my AppName... just feels odd having to do so. I was probably thinking of leaving my AppName as unlocalized so that i can have more of an identity across territories, though I don't know if this is a good thing or not.

Would be good for now if i could just make the app icon behave consistently with $PRODUCT_NAME being evaluated rather than being output literally in non-English languages.

Thanks for your time

Comment: I couldn't fix this at all.. turned out to be a simulator only issue at least so i guess in the scheme of things its not too bad.

I even got to the point where I'd removed all references to $PRODUCT_NAME in the plists and still on the simulator it was appearing on the app icon.. even on new simulator instances I'd not installed it on before. Very strange. It didn't do this with a simple test app vs my main app. Not sure what's different between them.